# Need to update specific XML node value using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to update the value of a particular node and save the file in the same name. I want to update the vendor name value:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<KioskSettings
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Settings>
        <Name>Store ID</Name>
        <Value>DEVQATEST</Value>
    </Settings>
    <Settings>
        <Name>Store Address</Name>
        <Value>ramapuram</Value>
    </Settings>
    <Settings>
        <Name>City Name</Name>
        <Value>chennai</Value>
    </Settings>
    <Settings>
        <Name>State</Name>
        <Value>Oklahoma</Value>
    </Settings>
    <Settings>
        <Name>Zip Code</Name>
        <Value>464</Value>
    </Settings>
    <Settings>
        <Name>Store Prefix</Name>
        <Value>DEV</Value>
    </Settings>
    <Settings>
        <Name>Vendor Name</Name>
        <Value>Bed Bath And Beyond</Value>
</KioskSettings>
```

Powershell

```bsh
$xmlfilepath = 'C:\Kiosk\Settings\ApplicationSettings.xml'
$content =[xml] (get-content $xmlfilepath)
$value=$content.KioskSettings.Settings[6].Value='AFFES'
$content.Save([console]::out)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain properly formatted XML by enclosing it in 3 leading & 3 trailing backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I figured out what I was doing wrong! I asked the script to save the doc but never told where to save it.

My bad..

This works for me :)

```
[xml] $content = get-content 'C:\test\test\Test.xml';$value=$content.KioskSettings.Settings[6].Value='AFFES';$content.Save('C:\test\test\TestSettings.xml')
```